# Ignoring features outside the Area of interest in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, features, filter, qgsmapcanvas

I have layers (shapefile and GDB) in my map that have more than 100,000 features. I am not editing them but just using them as a reference. I work only in a particular small area at one time. But my map is still slow because it is loading thousands of features.

Is there a way to set a filter in a QGIS project to ignore everything that is outside a particular area, so that the map is faster?

Comment: Are you using shapefiles?

Comment: The answer comes down to the data sources / file formats you're using. If the format supports spatial indexing, QGIS can apply an efficient filter.

Comment: I am using shapefiles and GDB format

Comment: @DPSSpatial can you answer this?

Comment: @underdark can you answer this?

Comment: @Someone191 at a certain point, you need to switch formats. Much like a notepad file eventually turns into a word document, a shapefile needs to go into a database where it can be properly indexed and retrieved in the way you need. If the index of the shapefile doesn't work, I recommend looking into a postgresql/postgis database.

Comment: @DPSSpatial:I can put the shapefiles into DB. What should I do after that to get what I wanted in the original question.

Comment: In a PostGIS DB, you could create a materialized view of your area of interest.

Comment: @Someone191 if you get your data into PostGIS, for example, and properly index your data (spatial and primary key), I would imagine your problems would be over. We use parcel and address point data that is almost unusable in QGIS with shapefile format. Once we put them in PostGIS, panning was seamless at all scales.

Answer (score 0):

For Shapefiles, you can create a spatial index, as documented in https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html#esri-shapefile-format

> 1. Load an ESRI Shapefile format dataset (see The Browser Panel)
> 2. Open the Layer Properties dialog by double-clicking on the layer    name in the legend or by right-clicking and choosing Properties…     from the context menu
> 3. In the Source tab, click the Create Spatial Index button

Comment: Just creatin an index won't solve the issue I have. Please expand your answer to include what to do after creating spatial index.